# preg_match сгруппированный результат

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вопрос вот в чем:

Есть такое выражение:

`preg_match("/(www)\.(example)\.(com)\/(news\/id-\d+|articles\/\d+)\.(html)/", $string, $matches);`

Введем 2 тестовые строчки для проверки нашего выражения:

```
www.example.com/news/id-345.html
www.example.com/articles/145.html
```

Выведет следующее:

```
Match 1
1.  www
2.  example
3.  com
4.  news/id-345
5.  html

Match 2
1.  www
2.  example
3.  com
4.  articles/145
5.  html
```

Как вы можете увидеть 4ый пункт содержит сразу 2 строчки, которые я хотел бы разбить...знаю что можно отдельно выделить в группе подгруппы (сделать скобки в скобках) тогда получится что будет и 4ая строка как была плюс разбитый вариант, но хочется чтобы не было такой 4ой строки с не разбитыми строчками

То есть хочу так:

```
Match 1
1.  www
2.  example
3.  com
4.  news
5.  id-345
6.  html

Match 2
1.  www
2.  example
3.  com
4.  articles
5.  145
6.  html
```

Возможно ли написать такое выражение? Если да то как?!

На PCRE можно написать так:

```
(www)\.(example)\.(com)\/(?:(?|(news)\/(id-\d+))|(?|(articles)\/(\d+)))\.(html)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6wI6WacwzBloPC-C)

Но при тесте в онлайн сервисах группы выдает не правильно

```
www.example.com/news/id-345.html
1. www
2. example
3. com
4. news
5. id-345
6. 
7. 
8. html

www.example.com/articles/345.html
1. www
2. example
3. com
4. 
5. 
6. articles
7. 345
8. html
```

Как избавиться от этих пропусков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так получилось что я смог самостоятельно написать и вот что в итоге вышло:

```
(www)\.(example)\.(com)\/(?|(news)\/(id-\d+)|(articles)\/(\d+))\.(html)
```

Прогоняем строки:

```
www.example.com/news/id-345.html
www.example.com/articles/345.html
www.example.com/news/art-345.html
www.example.com/articles/id-345.html
www.example.com/news/345.html
```

Что выдает редактор проверки регулярок:

```
www.example.com/news/id-345.html
1. www
2. example
3. com
4. news
5. id-345
6. html

www.example.com/articles/345.html
1. www
2. example
3. com
4. articles
5. 345
6. html

www.example.com/news/art-345.html
Не найдено соответствий

www.example.com/articles/id-345.html
Не найдено соответствий

www.example.com/news/345.html
Не найдено соответствий
```

Q:В чем суть и почему это выражение работает и тут нет пропускных групп?

A:Создана группа для разных вариантов набора ссылки причем не создаются пустые группы. `(?|...)` - Делает при разных условиях группы под одними и теми же номерами

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите внимательно на вашу регулярку, особенно на часть "(news/\d+|articles/\d+)". Ее можно, а правильнее даже нужно, разбить на две части: в одной news|articles, а во второй все остальное.

В итоге регулярка должна быть [такой](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28www%29%5C.%28example%29%5C.%28com%29%5C%2F%28news%7Carticles%29%5C%2F%28.*%3F%29%5C.%28html%29%2F).

Comment: обновил условие посмотрите

Comment: @MaximPro, ну и ленивы вы :) Поэтому сделал с помощью "ленивого" квантификатора. Обновил ответ

Comment: ну понимаете у вас вместо `id-345` может быть `art-345`, а нужно что бы именно было `id-` а потом число любого размера